# PyCharm breakpoint in external libraries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

Within PyCharm is it possible to place breakpoints in and step through external python libraries?

For context, I am following the Django REST framework quick start guide: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

However I'm unable to start the application as it throws the following exception:

Exception Value:
`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
Exception Location: /Users/yongli/code/shopfront/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py in get_default_base_name, line 141

I would like to be able to check the stack trace and step through the Django REST framework code to get to the root of this.

Comment: Yes, for me breakpoints in libraries work pretty well.
Doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov I've tried to no avail inserting a break point in the editor and also by set the debugger to suspend on exceptions. Are you aware of any setting that needs to be enabled to allow library debugging?

Comment: No, it worked for me from the box.
How do you get to the file ? Mb you open the file from wrong virtualenv or wrong py version ?
How about stepping into the library file while debugging your python code and then setting bp there, does it work that way ?

Comment: The break points in the external libraries are not being hit when I debug. I can step into them from my projects code, but if I set the break point in the external library module, it is ignored.

Comment: I just had the same problem, turns out i was starting a different project with a very similar structure and the same entrypoint name

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can just try using the smallest step possible.